# Comparing coefficients in identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $A\cos(\theta) + B\sin (\theta) = R\cos( \theta + \alpha)$ is an identity where $A, B, R \text{ and } \alpha$ are constants, how do you prove that the coefficients of $\cos(\theta)$ on either side of the identity must be equal? (and the same for $\sin(\theta)$).

Comment: There is no $\cos (\theta)$ term on the right side.  I think you're confused by what a coefficient means, but not sure.  feel free to follow up.

Comment: If you expand the bracket on the right hand side there will be a cos (theta) term.

Answer (score 1):

$$
A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta = R\cos(\theta + \alpha)\\
A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta = R\left(\cos\theta\cos\alpha-\sin\theta\sin\alpha\right)\\
\left(R\cos\alpha-A\right)\cos\theta = \left(R\sin\alpha+B\right)\sin\theta\\
$$
The above expression is true for every real $\theta$. So,
$$
\theta = 0\implies R\cos\alpha-A=0 \\
\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\implies R\sin\alpha+B=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

If I have $$A\cos\theta +B\sin \theta=R\cos(\theta+\alpha)=R\cos\theta\cos\alpha-R\sin\theta\sin \alpha$$ as an identity, I can choose $\theta=0$ to obtain $A=R\cos\alpha$,

and $\theta=90^{\circ}=\frac {\pi}2\text{ radians}$ to obtain $B=-R\sin\alpha$

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know that those values obtained are unique?

Comment: @Mathperson - I'm not sure what you mean. If I choose $\theta$ so that $\sin\theta=0, \cos\theta=1$ I get $A=R\cos\alpha$. If that is not true I don't have an identity valid for all $\theta$ because it doesn't work for the special one I chose.